# How do I Find Range Values Present On Another Range Values

Tags: php, optimization, range

Find the range values between another range values,
Below code is working fine, But i need any other optimized way.

```
<?php
$lmi = 1000;
$lmx = 20000;
$cmi = 19000;
$cmx = 40000;
$cnt = count(array_intersect(range($lmi,$lmx),range($cmi,$cmx)));
print_r($cnt);
?>
```

If anyone find the solution please share to me..Thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to compute the amount of overlap, try:

```
$overlap = ($lmx < $cmi || $cmx < $lmi) ? 0 : min($lmx-$cmi, $cmx-$lmi);
print_r($overlap);
```

This returns zero if there is no overlap and the amount of overlap otherwise.